# JSoup not printing all elements in HTML table row

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to get all the elements in a HTML table row using JSoup. However, it seems to consistently omit columns and print only about half of the columns in the table. For instance, if I have an HTML table like so:

```
<table id="resultTable" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table">
            <td align="right">1</td>
            <td align="right">4</td>
            <td><div>NAME</div></td>
            <td><div>Country</div></td>
            <td><div>Club</div></td>
            <td><div>SR</div></td>
            <td align="right"><div>56.00 (5)</div></td>
            <td align="right"><div>51.62 (3)</div></td>
            <td align="right"><div>1:47.62</div></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And I try printing the cells like so:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);  //html is a string containing the full HTML page
Elements tableRows = doc.select("tr.table");

for (Element tableRow : tableRows) {
    
    System.out.println(tableRow.text());

}
```

For some reason, the only cells that are ever printed are the 1st, 3rd and 9th cell.

You  can find the full HTML [here](http://live-timing.com/race2.php?r=163390). (It's a website used for displaying live timing of alpine ski races). For the sake of brevity I only included one `<tr>` tag, but the website contains hundreds of them. Also, I don't know if it matters, but every `<div>` calls a Javascript function `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

Is the problem a bad HTML? I thought JSoup took care or cleaning bad HTML. Or am I not using JSoup properly?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** Fixed it. As I was using and Android WebView, I had not realized I was loading the mobile site instead of the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure which the `html` is: *`the source downloaded from the url`* or *`the full html copied from browser`*.If *`the source`*, you will get nothing due to the page is dynamic and the table load by *http://live-timing.com/includes/aj_race.php?r=163390&&m=1&&u=5*(*maybe you can try to get result directly from this url*).If *`the full html`*, your selector syntax has no problem, you can try in *https://try.jsoup.org/*, the result is correct.

Comment: indeed I do make sure all the content is loaded before parsing. I still think it's weird behavior though, because whenever I try with a similar (but different) website everything works perfectly.

Comment: @justbourv Just a moment ago, i did save the page to local file demo.html from  my browser and i read it in my program to `String html`, then i ran your code. The result is correct, it printed the whole cells. My jsoup version is `1.8.3`. So i think your problem is exactly in your `html`. What did you use to load the page, slenium? or else? Try to compare your `html` with `the whole html in a real browser`.

Comment: Weird. I use a `Webview` on Android. Maybe that's the problem, I'll check out selenium